# Media Gallery not using lightbox and required libraries are in place. What is wrong?

Tags: 7, javascript, media

I'm trying to make a Gallery utilizing lightbox on my Drupal 7.26 site.
I've picked [Media Gallery](https://drupal.org/project/media_gallery) (7.x-1.0-beta8) and as it says it requires the following compulsory components to work:

- Media (1.4)
- Multiform (1.0)
- ColorBox jQuery plugin

I've extracted a colorbox-master.zip under `sites/all/libraries` and renamed `colorbox-master` folder to `colorbox`. Now the `sites/all` looks like this.

[image: showing locations of various modules/libraries]

I also have the colorbox module installed.

The images in the gallery doesn't seem to use any lightbox at all when clicked upon. I've checked a couple of other solutions elsewhere and I think I've gotten all of them covered as you can see on the screenshot above. Nothing else seems to help.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the colorbox folder/file permissions in libraries. I had a simillar issue in loading the CkEditor.

Comment: Thanks! Giving sites/all/libraries/colorbox full read/write permission solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bala Varadarajan suggested. I gave `sites/all/libraries/colorbox/` and all its contents **full Read/Write** permissions.

The lightbox is working now.

Comment: Perhaps you could let Bala Varadarajan create the answer for this question as he actually answered this for you in the comments and then you can upvote and accept their answer to give him credit for his efforts to help you.

Comment: He is welcome to do so. If in two days I find his answer I will always upvote and approve that over mine.